# How to make a remote function call to the parent browser window?

Tags: javascript

I open a new window with code something like this:

```
var childWin = window.open('some.html,'_blank');
```

Is it possible for me to make a function call from the child window, something like the following?

```
var result = parent.makeCall('someMethod');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. You reference the parent with window.opener.

```
window.opener.someMethod();
```

If you want to go the reverse way, you would use the variable in which you store the window reference.

```
childWin.methodName();
```